# Typescript error; any Property 'button' does not exist on type 'CellDetails | ContentCellUpdate'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am wanting to check if a property exists on an object, but the property only exists `CellDetails` not on `ContentCellUpdate`

Currently I am doing,

```
if(cell.button)
```

cell can either by CellDetails or ContentCellUpdate

but I get the error in TS,

> Property 'button' does not exist on type 'CellDetails | ContentCellUpdate'.
> Property 'button' does not exist on type 'ContentCellUpdate'

The interfaces for each look like this,

```
export interface CellDetails {
  row: number;
  col: any;
  column: any;
  content: ContentCell;
  header: boolean;
  button: ActionsButton | null;
  reference: string;
  history: boolean;
  link: IPageContentLink | null;
  image: boolean;
  isColumnCheckbox: boolean;
  permission: string;
  inputStyles: string;
  cell: HTMLDivElement;
}
```

and

```
export interface ContentCellUpdate {
  row: number;
  column: string;
  content: ContentCellFormat;
}
```

I assume that I could add,

button: ActionsButton | null;

to ContentCellUpdate, but this feels like fixing the symptom rather than the cause? Is there a better way to get around this TS error?

Comment: you can add the button prop to the other interface, or if you know that cell will be of one type, you can use as to cast it to the required interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `hasOwnProperty()` method, your code will be something like this:

```
if (cell.hasOwnProperty('button')) {

}
```